# Remapping Alt + F2 in Unity

Tags: unity, compiz, shortcuts

I disabled the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> default shortcut in unity (ubuntu 11.10) using ccsm and I set a new shortcut using the default system shortcut manager (system settings > keyboard). And it works, until I execute a command like `compiz --replace`. After that, all shortcuts keep working normally, except for <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>. It does nothing.

Any suggetions to keep the custom <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> shortcut working after `compiz --replace`?

Answer (score 2):

Install gconf-editor if you don't have it.  `sudo apt-get install gconf-editor`
Under Apps-compiz-1-plugins-unityshell-screen0-options set execute command to whatever you want it remapped to be.

One example could be <kbd>Alt</kbd>.  If you want to set it to something that is already occupied(in the case of this example <kbd>Alt</kbd>, you may need to unset that shortcut in keyboard shortcuts first).

Reports indicate that setting it to nothing is ineffective.  I would recommend setting it to something you don't anticipate using.

[image]

Comment: Can I change key combination somehow? Because I need to press 3 buttons (alt+Fn+F2) to make it work, but that is exactly what I wanted, thanks.

Comment: @hey This might be a silly question but is it possible you are confusing the HUD with the Dash? (apologises if I am way off here)

Comment: @StephenMyall: Probably yes. :) I don't see how HUD is good yet, but what aking suggested is a thing I wanted.

Comment: You may have better luck the changing the wording of the question from Hud to dash.  this way you might be able to achieve your objective.  The HUD is new to most and once you become familiar you will begin to understand its value.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I managed to do this with Unity

- Install *CompizConfig* by execute

  `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
- Open *CompizConfig* by typing "compiz" into your launcher or `ccsm` in terminal.
- Choose *Advanced search*, enter `execute a command` into the search box, choose *Ubuntu Unity Plugin* on the right.
- Edit the shortcut into something else, like `Alt F3` and voila!

Credit: https://askubuntu.com/a/323945/189124

Answer (score 0):

I would think this may be because of the order in which 'plugins' are loading. I would ensure that the setting has been changed in Unity. CCSM may be making the change under metacity.

I use gconf-editor (which is not installed by default); you can install by doing:

> sudo apt-get install gconf-editor

After launching gconf-editor you navigate the tree:

> apps > compiz-1 > plugins > unityshell > screen0 > options

There will be a setting in the right hand column 'execute_command' with a value of `<Alt>F2` change this to Disabled or set a new combination.

[image]

Comment: That did not work. It was already disabled. I tried to set the shortcut using xbindkeys and after applying the shortcut it works again. But I have to do that everytime I use the `compiz --replace`. I know it is a good clue but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: I am not sure... but it sounds like there is some base setting overriding your changes.