# How to set Hud to do this?

Tags: unity, 12.04, hud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remapping Alt + F2 in Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76576/remapping-alt-f2-in-unity)

I don't want to use launcher at all, i just want to use Hud. For example, I press Alt and write Chr and press enter and it will open Chrome. Or I press folder_name + enter and it opens that folder. But at the moment, it seems I can't do that. Is it possible to set it somehow? That would be awesome, thank you.