# Disable unity launcher on Alt + F2

Tags: unity, 13.04, shortcut-keys, launcher

I've added custom shortcut on <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, but Unity launcher is running when I press it. How do I disable it in 13.04. I've found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76576/remapping-alt-f2-in-unity) but I don't have 'unityshell' under `apps > compiz-1 > plugins`

Screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CompizConfig to do this.

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` in a terminal to install, and then type "CompizConfig" into your Dash to find it, or `ccsm` in the terminal.

Once it's open, scroll to the "Ubuntu Unity Plugin" option and click it.

On the General tab, you will see some options related to keyboard shortcuts. Find "Key to execute a command" (second option down), and click the shortcut ("<Alt>F2" by default). Uncheck the box in the popup window that says "Enabled", and click OK. From then on the alt-f2 shortcut to bring up the command window will be disabled.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @RiaD Huh. Hadn't noticed that, thanks for spotting (thank heavens for the &lt; and &gt; codes!)

Comment: this worked, but I am not sure if before or after the some messing about with gconf-editor and dconf-editor. I find all those setting managers so confusing.........

Answer (score 0):

Newer Ubuntu versions (following GNOME in this regard) use the DConf binary database instead of the old textual GConf db. So if such option still exists, it can be edited with `dconf-editor`.

Comment: It's cool. But It hasn't even `apps/compiz-1`

Comment: The path most likely changed, I would guess com.canonical ... or something like that, unfortunately can't check it now.