# Make custom shortcut on Alt+F2

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I'm using 13.04.

I want to make `gmrun` run when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>. I've already [made <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> disabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323936/disable-untity-launcher-on-alt-f2)

1. I add custom shortcut in `All-settings/Keyboard/Shortcuts`

   [image]

   Everything works fine.
2. I reboot and the shortcut doesn't work (Nothing happens).
3. I click on Alt+F2, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and the shortcut works again

I've tested it with few key combinations.

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> - situation as described above.
- <kbd>Menu</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> - works fine

**The question is how to make shortcut on <kbd>ALt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> permanent**

Comment: Have you tried with other keys? Alt+F2 is already used by the system (by default).

Comment: @edwin, I've already disabled Alt+F2 in system. I've tried with Alt+F6 too.

Comment: Works fine with menu, through.

Comment: I've noticed that there is `Alt(Tap)` and `Alt(hold)` default shortcuts. And it may be the problem.  I've managed to switch off first, but not the second(which doesn't seem to work). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make it working using CompisConfig Settings Manager.

First of all I didn't understand when others shortcuts with Alt start working. I believed It was right after I disabled "Key to show the HUD" in "Ubuntu unity plugin" section is CCSM but they still work now, when I reenable it.

You need to Disable "Key to execute command" in "Ubuntu unity plugin" section **and also disable "Run Dialog" in "Gnome compatibility" section**.

[image: screen]

To disable any shortcut you need click to current shortcut and remove "Enabled" checkbox, then "OK"

[image: screen][image: screen]